# How does the weak topology imply the definition of weak convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then the weak topology on $X$ is defined as the coarsest topology such that the linear functionals in $X^*$ are continuous. A sequence $x_n \in X$ weakly converges to $x$ if and only if
$$f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x), \quad \forall f \in X^*. \tag{1}$$

Similarly, the weak* topology on $X^*$ is defined as the coarsest topology such that the evaluation functionals $x(f) \mapsto f(x)$ are continuous. A sequence $f_n \in x^*$ is said to converge to $f$ in this topology if
$$f_n(x) \rightarrow f, \quad \forall x \in X. \tag{2}$$

(1) and (2) are often given as definitions, but I would like to get a better insight into how these definitions follow from their respective topologies. Does this follow from their neighborhood bases at 0? For example in the weak topology such a neighorhood takes the form
$$N(f_1,...,f_n;\epsilon)=\{x :|f_i(x)|<\epsilon, \text{for }i=1,\dots,n\}.$$
If so, how does this neighborhood base imply (1), and similarly for the weak* topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the weak topology is in particular a topology where all functionals are continuous. So if $x_n\to x$ in $X$ under the weak topology, it is necessarily the case - by continuity of $f$ - that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$), for any $f\in X^\ast$.

If you like, you can see that explicitly via the explicit basis. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $f\in X^\ast$. $N(f;\epsilon)(x)$ is a weak neighbourhood of $x$ and thus contains $x_n$ for all large $n\ge N$. That means exactly that $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$... by arbitrariness, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ follows.

The same remarks apply for the weak-$\star$ topology.

An interesting question is whether or not property $(1)$ fully characterises the weak topology. I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Regarding the last question, sequential convergence in the weak topology does not characterise the topology because each infinite-dimensional normed space equipped with the weak topology is a non-metrisable locally convex space. Nets are required to characterise the topology in that manner.

Comment: On another note, $\ell_{1}$ is an example of a Banach space which has Schur's property, which is that a sequence converges weakly to a limit if, and only if, it converges in norm to the same limit. However, $\ell_{1}$ equipped with the weak topology is distinct from $\ell_{1}$ equipped with the norm topology, because one is metrisable while the other is not. This provides an example of why sequences cannot characterise convergence in the weak topology in general.